# Create Dataframes iteratively from columns of another Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

Say I have a df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A.C.1_v': [1, 2, 3], 'B': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'C.C.1_f': [4, 5, 6], 'D': ['e', 'f', 'g'], 'E': [7, 8, 9]})
```

Noticed that the col of interest are those nmae includes "C.1_letter"

I have built a list corresponding of selected columns : col_list = [A.C.1_v, C.C.1_f]

Objective : Create several dataframe**s** as follow (in this illustration only 2 dfs are built, but there could be much more in practice)

The first df

1. Takes the name with the following convention name : "df_AC1_v"
2. Is composed of the values of column A.C.1_v and the values of columns D and E

So, for df_AC1_v we would have the following output:
[output 1 without iteration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XMUH.png)

The second df

1. Takes the name with the following convention name : "df_CC1_f"
2. Is composed of the values of column C.C.1_f and the values of columns D and E
   So, for df_CC1_f, we would have the following output:
   [Output2 without iteration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6cUg.png)

My point is to do this iteratively, but so far, what I have attempted does not work.

Here are the codes I have done.  It bugs in the loop for and I do not understand why.
First I extract the col list and create a list as follow:

```
col_list = list(df)
list_c1 = list(filter(lambda x:'.C.1' in x, col_list))
list_c1 = [str(r) for r in list_c1]
```

in: `list_c1`
out:['A.C.1_v', 'C.C.1_f']

Second I isolate the 'C.1'

```
list_c1_bis = []
for element in list_c1:
    stock = element.split('.C.1')
    list_c1_bis.append(stock)
```

in : `list_c1_bis`
out:[['A', '_v'], ['C', '_f']]

Until now, I am happy.  Where it bugs is the code below:

```
for line in list_c1_bis:
    name1 ='df'+'_'+line[0]+'C1'+line[1]
    vars()[name1] =  df[[list_c1[0],'D','E']]
```

My outputs are indeed as follow:
in: `df_AC1_v` ==> OK correct
out:
[output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oU2My.png)

in: `df_CC1_f` ==> **Wrong** it has taken the inappropriate column A.C.1_v, instead of expected C.C.1_f
[output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRnmy.png)

Your suggestions are welcome !

Thanks a lot for your time and help, that will be truly appreciated

nb : please feel free to modify the first steps that work if you think you have a better solution

Kindest regards

Comment: And the column `B`?

Comment: Please provide the expected output as code/text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly discouraged you to create variables dynamically with `vars`, `locals` or `globals`. Prefer to use dictionary.

Try

```
for col in df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(r'[A-Z]\.[0-9]_[a-z]')]:
    name = col.replace('.', '')
    locals()[f"df_{name}"] = df[[col, 'D', 'E']]
```

**Update**

If `f-strings` are not available (Python < 3.6), replace `locals()[f"df_{name}"]` by `locals()["df_{}".format(name)]`.

Output:

```
>>> df_AC1_v
   A.C.1_v  D  E
0        1  e  7
1        2  f  8
2        3  g  9

>>> df_CC1_f
   C.C.1_f  D  E
0        4  e  7
1        5  f  8
2        6  g  9
```

**Alternative** with dictionary:

```
dfs = {}
for col in df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(r'[A-Z]\.[0-9]_[a-z]')]:
    name = col.replace('.', '')
    dfs[name] = df[[col, 'D', 'E']]
```

Output:

```
>>> dfs['AC1_v']
   A.C.1_v  D  E
0        1  e  7
1        2  f  8
2        3  g  9

>>> dfs['CC1_f']
   C.C.1_f  D  E
0        4  e  7
1        5  f  8
2        6  g  9
```

Comment: Maybe show the dictionary alternative as main answer as encouragement to use it ;)

Comment: The OP already uses `vars()`. I think he knows what he's doing :)

Comment: Still, this is a **very bad** practice to fight ;)

Comment: Hi Corralien, I have replied, so perhaps you can have a look.  Kindest regards

Comment: Thanks Corralien, it works perfectly.  Kindest regards

Answer (score 0):

Hi Corralien and first let me thank you for your prompt reply that is truly appreciated.

I have tried the first code

```
for col in df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(r'[A-Z]\.[0-9]_[a-z]')]:
    name = col.replace('.', '')
    locals()[f"df_{name}"] = df[[col, 'D', 'E']]
```

But, I have the following error :
File "", line 3
locals()[f"df_{name}"] = df[[col, 'D', 'E']]
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I have also tried the second proposed code that gives the solution under dictionary.

```
dfs = {}
for col in df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(r'[A-Z]\.[0-9]_[a-z]')]:
    name = col.replace('.', '')
    dfs[name] = df[[col, 'D', 'E']]
```

It runs without error, but when I check the existence of the DFs
in: `df_AC1_v`

I have the following errors :
NameError: name 'df_AC1_v' is not defined

I understand that to get the df , it is required to write : dfs['AC1_v']

The second solution is acceptable, but I would prefer the first solution if it worked.

Kindest regards

Comment: Do you use a version of Python prior to 3.6?